# Código de confirmação

Tags: java, algoritmo, while

Queria fazer um esquema para confirmar uma pergunta. Caso a resposta fosse SiM para a pergunta apareceria uma mensagem de ok. Caso fosse Nao ou diferente de Sim, perguntaria se a pessoa gostaria de confirmar de novo. Fiz esse algoritmo ai, mas não entra no loop.

```
package resposta;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Resposta {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Confirma?");
        String resp = " ";
        String conf = sc.nextLine();
        while(resp.equals("s")){
            if(resp == "s"){
                System.out.println("confirmado");
            }else{
                String resp2 = "Confirme?";
                conf = sc.nextLine();
                conf = conf + 1;

            }
        }


        sc.close();

    }


    }
```

Comment: Por quê você usa `resp` e `conf` como duas variáveis e não apenas uma só?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 8):

O código está complicando o que não precisa:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String resp = " ";
        while (!resp.equals("s")) {
            System.out.println("Confirma?");
            resp = sc.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("confirmado");
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1E87CE). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Confirmationjava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Confirmation.java).

Não precisa perguntar duas vezes. Não precisa verificar de novo dentro do laço o que já está sendo verificado na condição do laço. Eu estou aceitando entrar inicialmente de qualquer jeito e ele fica no laço até que a letra `s` seja digitada. Quando isto acontecer o laço será encerrado, ele confirma e encerra a aplicação.

Eu simplifiquei o que nem estava sendo usada e tirei o que nem fazia sentido. Eu simplificaria um pouco mais, mas nem todo mundo desse jeito. Eu tinha reduzo a quantidade de variáveis, agora faço mais ainda:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Confirma?");
            if (sc.nextLine().equals("s")) break;
        }
        System.out.println("confirmado");
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DwsYIS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Confirmation2java). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Confirmation2.java).

Comment: Valeu meu amigo, deu certinho. Obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @AdautoAlmeida veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrrigado.